# $\lim\limits_{y \to 0} \frac{y}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(x)}{x^2+y^2} \, dx = f(0)$ if $f$ is continuously differentiable and bounded

Tags: integration, limits, continuity

I wish to find a cleaner proof of the fact that $\lim\limits_{y \to 0} \frac{y}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^2+y^2} \, dx = f(0)$ if $f$ is continuously differentiable and bounded.

Since $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{y}{\pi(x^2+y^2)} = 1,$ setting $g(x) = f(x)-f(0)$ reduces this problem to proving $\lim\limits_{y \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{yg(x)}{x^2+y^2} = 0$ for all continuously differentiable and bounded $g$ satisfying $g(0) = 0.$

Since we are given a differentiability hypothesis, one idea is to integrate by parts: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{yg(x)}{x^2+y^2} \, dx = g(x)\tan^{-1}(x/y) \Big|_{-\infty}^{\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g'(x)\tan^{-1}(x/y) \, dx.$ However, $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} g(x)$ may not necessarily exist: consider $g(x) = \sin(x+1)$ for example.

Another option is reversing differentiation under the integral sign to obtain $\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dy} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \log(x^2+y^2)g(x) \, dx := 0.5h'(y)$ so that we wish to prove $h'$ is continuous and $h'(0) = 0.$ The continuity of $h'$ is clear and $h'(0) = \lim\limits_{y \to 0} \frac{h(y)-h(0)}{y} = \lim\limits_{y \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log(1+(y/x)^2)}{y} g(x) \, (*)$ Do not use L'Hopital's rule at this point or else you will be sent back to the start.

Suppose $|f| \le M.$ Then $\int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus (-\sqrt{y},\sqrt{y})} \left|\frac{\log(1+(y/x)^2)}{y} g(x)\right| \, dx \le \int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus (-\sqrt{y}, \sqrt{y})} \frac{M(y/x)^2}{y} \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus (-\sqrt{y},\sqrt{y})} \frac{My}{x^2} \, dx = -My/x \Big|_{\sqrt{y}}^{\infty} - My/x \Big|_{-\infty}^{-\sqrt{y}} = 2M\sqrt{y}.$ 
Furthermore, $|\frac{\log(1+(y/x)^2)}{y} g(x)| = |\frac{\log(1+(y/x)^2)}{y/x} \frac{g(x)}{x}| \le |r(y/x)\frac{g(x)}{x}|$ where $r(t) = \frac{\log(1+t^2)}{t}.$ Since $\lim\limits_{t \to 0} r(t)$ exists, $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{g(x)}{x} = g'(0)$ exists,  and $r$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R},$ we know $\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}} \left|\frac{\log(1+(y/x)^2)}{y} g(x)\right|$ exists and $\left|\frac{\log(1+(y/x)^2)}{y} g(x) \right| \le N$ for some $N.$ Then the integral in $(*)$ is at most $2M\sqrt{y} + 2N\sqrt{y},$ which tends to $0$ as $y \to 0.$

There should be a method that avoids having to jump through so many hoops like this. I also considered rewriting the original integral as a double integral $dx dy,$ but this doesn't work since the integrand will then contain $\frac{d}{dy} \frac{y}{x^2+y^2},$ which is very messy. Using $dx dt$ and letting a function of $t$ be integrated over $[a,y]$ for some suitable $a$ (possibly $\pm \infty$) did not inspire any great choices.

I used the existence of $g'(0),$ but not the continuity of $g',$ which seems fishy. Did I accidentally use the continuity of $g'$ somewhere? If not, perhaps the simpler proof I seek would use that information to its full potential.

Comment: Substitute $x=yt$ and apply [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Comment: For what its worth, although the proof is not "short and sweet", it works for a large collection of kernels. What you have is the Poisson kernel for the half-plane, but you can more generally have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Approximations_to_the_identity or I would assume any textbook on Fourier Analysis

Comment: Actually I'm not so sure if your proof is watertight, it might be better to decouple the cutoff region $[-\sqrt y,\sqrt y]$ from the small parameter $y\to 0$, see pdf below. We have the scaling property
$$ \phi_y(x) := \frac y {\pi(x^2+y^2)} = \frac1y\frac1{\pi((x/y)^2+1)} = \frac1y\phi_1\left(\frac xy\right)$$
where the function $\phi_1\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ and $\phi_1\ge 0$. For such functions,  there is a standard proof, see section 4, in particular remark 4.9 and proposition 4.10 of  http://www2.math.uu.se/~rosko894/teaching/Part_04_Fourier%20analysis_ver_1.0.pdf